# Fast calculation of sum for function defined over range of integers - (0,2^52)

Tags: python, math, statistics

I was looking at the code for a particular cryptocurrency casino game (EthCrash - if you're interested). The game generates crash points using a function (I call this crash(x)) where x is an integer that is randomly drawn from the space of integers (0,2^52).

I'd like to calculate the expected value of the crash points. The code below should explain everything, but a clean picture of the function is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdZIh.png, and what I'm trying to calculate is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdE91.png (apologies - can't paste pictures yet).

I wrote the following code:

```
import math

two52 = 2**52

def crash(x):    
    crash_point = math.floor((100*two52-x)/(two52-x))
    return(crash_point/100)

crashes_sum = 0

for i in range(two52+1):
    crashes_sum += crash(i)

expected_crash = crashes_sum/two52
```

Unfortunately, the loop is taking too long to run - any ideas for how I can do this faster?

Comment: You have to test `4_503_599_627_370_496` values... at 1GHz (`1_000_000_000` loops per second) this will take you 52 days...

Comment: Appreciate your comment - it does confirm that this loop won't do the job. Still hoping someone has a method of doing it faster.

Comment: Do you know if your guess is too high or too low? Or do you only know if it is or isnt the correct value?

Comment: Hey Grant - not sure what you mean by guess - I don't really have any intuition about what this mean is going to be

Comment: Every value for `crash(x)` is 1 for at least `range(2**45)`.

Comment: ....But it's only 1% of every possible value...

Comment: @TwistedSim I proposed something similar, please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

ok, if you cannot do it straightforward, time to get smart, right?
So idea to get ranges where whole sum could be computed fast. I will put some pseudocode which not even compiles, could have bugs etc. Use it as illustration.

First, lets rewrite the term in the sum as

floor( 100 + 99*x/(2<sup>52</sup> - x) )

First idea - get ranges where floor is not changing due to the fact that term 
n =< 99*x/(2<sup>52</sup> - x) < n+1. Obviously, for this whole range we could add to sum range_length*(100 + n), no need to do it term by term

```
sum  = 0
r_lo = 0
for k in range(0, 2*52): # LOOP OVER RANGES
    r_hi = floor(2**52/(1 + 99/n))
    sum += (100 + n -1)*(r_hi - r_lo)
    if r_hi-r_lo == 1:
        break
    r_lo = r_hi + 1
```

Obviously, range size will shrink till it is equal to 1, and then this method will be useless, we break out. Obviously, by that time each term would be different from previous one by 1 or more.

Ok, second idea - again ranges, where sum is [arithmetic series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html). First we have to find range where increment is equal to 1. Then range where increment is equal to 2, etc. Looks like you have to find roots of quadratic equation for this, but code would be about the same

```
r_lo = pos_for_increment(1)
t_lo = ... # term at r_lo
for n in range(2, 2*52): # LOOP OVER RANGES
    r_hi = pos_for_increment(n) - 1
    t_hi = ... # term at r_lo
    sum += (t_lo + t_hi)*(r_hi - r_lo) / 2 # arith.series sum
    if r_hi > 2**52:
        break
    r_lo = r_hi + 1
    t_lo = t_hi + n
```

might think about something else, but those tricks are worth trying

Answer (score 0):

Using the **map** function might help increase the speed since it makes the computation in parallel

```
import math

two52 = 2**52

def crash(x):    
    crash_point = math.floor((100*two52-x)/(two52-x))
    return(crash_point/100)

crashes_sum = sum(map(crash,range(two52)))

expected_crash = crashes_sum/two52
```

Comment: also `(100*two52-x) // (two52-x)` may be more efficient. But this will likely take many days/years on a normal computer. I barely get 1 millions iteration per seconds, which would be 52000 days.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to speed up your code by taking advantage of numpy vectorization:

```
import numpy as np
import time

two52 = 2**52
crash = lambda x: np.floor( ( 100 * two52 - x ) / ( two52 - x ) ) / 100

starttime = time.time()
icur = 0
ispan = 100000
crashes_sum = 0
while icur < two52-ispan:
    i = np.arange(icur, icur+ispan, 1)
    crashes_sum += np.sum(crash(i))
    icur += ispan
crashes_sum += np.sum(crash(np.arange(icur, two52, 1)))
expected_crash = crashes_sum / two52
print(time.time() - starttime)
```

The trick is to compute the sum on a moving windows to take advantage of numpy's vectorization (written in C). I tried up to 2**30 and it takes 9 seconds on my laptop (and too long for your code to be able to benchmark).

Python is probably not the most suitable language for what you want to do, you may want to try C or Fortran for that (and take advantage of threading).

Comment: (2^52/2^30)*9sec = ?

Comment: It's still gonna take about 100 days! The partial sum is the way to go I think.

Comment: Also, the computation up to 2^45 is trivial. The sum is just the number itself.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a powerful GPU if you wan't the result within some hours.

**A possible CPU implementation**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time

two52 = 2**52
loop_to=2**30

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def sum_over_crash(two52,loop_to): #loop_to is only for testing performance
  crashes_sum = nb.float64(0)
  for i in nb.prange(loop_to):#nb.prange(two52+1):
    crashes_sum += np.floor((100*two52-i)/(two52-i))/100

  return crashes_sum/two52

sum_over_crash(two52,2)#don't measure static compilation overhead
t1=time.time()
sum_over_crash(two52,2**30)
print(time.time()-t1)
```

This takes 0.57s for on my quadcore i7. eg. 28 days for the whole calculation.

Answer (score 0):

As the calculation can not be minimized mathematically, the only option is to calculate it step by step.

This takes a long time (as stated in other answers). Your best bet on calculating it fast is to use a lower level language than python. Since python is an interpreted language, it is rather slow to calculate this kind of thing.

Additionally you can use multithreading (if availible in the chosen language) to make it even faster.

Cloud Computing is also an option that could be suitable for this, as you are only going to calculate the number once. Amazon and Google (and many more) provide this kind of service for a relatively small fee.

But before performing any of the calculations you need to adjust your formula, as with the way it stands right now, you're going to get a *ZeroDivisionError* at the very last iteration of your loop.

Comment: `As the calculation can not be minimized mathematically` completely - no, but partial sums could be done, please check my answer